# How to download Ubuntu packages when you can't connect from an Ubuntu machine

Tags: software-center, downloads, search

How do I download software, besides the Ubuntu iso itself when you can't connect from an Ubuntu machine (e.g. from my Windows laptop)?  I've logged in to Ubuntu One, then into Canonical from Ubuntu One, but clicking on Canonical's 'software' button takes me to a webpage with nifty graphics and a link to use for downloading the Ubuntu iso itself, but when I am at the webpage I can't download any packages that I would normally be able to install in Ubuntu from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please give us a bit more information like: what exactly do you mean by "the U facility"?  Furthermore, your primary problem about buying software broke off right after "My laptop is" Could you *please* [edit] your question so we can forward the first problem to the site administrators and that we can take care of your primary problem?

Comment: I'd also add your question is cut off, and AU's essentially community support, rather than something owned/run by canonical proper.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking.

Comment: Virusboy, Journeyman Geek, Fabby:  I rewrote my question using the same subject line.

Comment: I think the problem may be that your assuming facts not in evidence and asking us to resolve your conclusion. Please edit your question after reviewing http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Visit [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) webpage, and under the heading that says **Search** type the name of the package you are searching for in the *Keyword:* text entry field, select your distribution from the dropdown menu to the right of where it says *Distribution:*, and click the **Search** button to show the search results.

The search results of Ubuntu Packages Search may contain more than one package. Select the package you want to download, select the operating system architecture (either amd64 or i386), select a download mirror which has a location close to you, and download the package.

In addition to searching for packages in all the **currently supported releases**, Ubuntu Packages Search also supports searching for packages from the **second latest release** even if that release is an EOL release. For example in September, 2018 the gcc package from the second latest release, Ubuntu 17.10, can still be found at `https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/gcc` as shown in the screenshot. This is useful when you need to download and install a missing package for 17.10 in order to upgrade it to 18.04, even if 17.10 is currently an End Of Life release.

[image]

Comment: This is how to download Ubuntu software from any web browser in any operating system. If this is not the answer that you were looking for, please comment so that I can fix it.

Comment: Thank you, Karel.  That seems to have worked.  I was able to download the pkg..  I will install it when I return home.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as your and the answerer's reputations will go up!  ;-)